# Is it possible using Jersey/JAX-RS annotations to skip a class member when marshalling to XML/JSON?

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Pretty straightforward question. I am using Jersey to build a REST system. If I have a class with a value that I need to use during processing but don't want sent as part of the XML or JSON output when the class is marshaled, is there a way to ignore it? Something like:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="example")
class Example {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private Object c;

    @XmlElement(ignore=true)
    public int getA() { return a; }
    @XmlElement
    public String getB() { return b; }
    @Ignore
    public Object getC() { return c; }
    ... //setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

I would hope that something like the `ignore=true` over `getA()` or the `@Ignore` over `getC()` would work, but i can find no documentation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are couple options depending on how many fields/properties you want to be ignored.

**Option #1 - `@XmlTransient`**

If you want less than half of the properties to be ignored then I would recommend annotating them with `@XmlTransient`.  This will exclude them from the XML mapping.

```java
@XmlRootElement
class Example {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private Object c;

    @XmlTransient
    public int getA() { return a; } // UNMAPPED

    public String getB() { return b; } // MAPPED

    @XmlTransient    
    public Object getC() { return c; } // UNMAPPED

    ... //setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

**Option #2 - `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`**

If you want more than half of the properties ignored I would recommend using the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation at the type level to set `XmlAccessType.NONE`.  This will cause only annotated properties to be mapped to XML.

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class Example {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private Object c;

    public int getA() { return a; } // UNMAPPED

    @XmlElement
    public String getB() { return b; } // MAPPED

    public Object getC() { return c; } // UNMAPPED

    ... //setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Comment: Thanks you made my day